Does small increase of oil intake increase health risks
I have a habit of sipping about a spoonful of rapeseed oil (mainly for omega fats) and olive oil (polyphenols) during mornings. Usually in empty stomach with water, most of the mornings I "fast". Both of the oils are said to improve health regarding heart and vessels, but I believe the claims are referring to replacing hard fats with the softer oils. Thus, if I already have a healthy diet with enough energy, could the two extra spoonfuls of oil each day actually increase health risks in longer run? I know there are a couple of related discussions, but they haven't considered the continuous intake of two spoonfuls each day as "breakfast", not to mention the particular combination of the oils. Is the amount significant or not regarding any health risks? Considering only the energy, two spoonfuls contain about 240 calories according to general internet sources, but I am not enough familiar with the units to draw any conclusions of that.
Edit: this question was closed as duplicate, although it clearly deals with both olive and rapeseed oil unlike the previous one. I will soon post my own answer to this question.

@Carey Gregory - I think this is on topic. Especially since every news source and health site on the internet has ads that say "Take a gulp of [olive oil] every night for [heart health]. That's a medical claim, not a nutritional claim.

@anongoodnurse Hmm... I see your point about it being a medical claim rather than nutritional claim. I'm still a bit on the fence about it, but I'll reopen.

@CareyGregory - I'm sorry, I didn't notice this was a duplicate, and not much has changed since Dr. Whom's comment. https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/15409/169
